# How do I send an Electronic I.D. so that I can post my music on a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, music

So basically I am a musician and I thought that putting my music on Facebook would be a good way of showing my friends and family with my recordings.

But When I connected with the music player App, it just wasn't there and so I did some searching and the help center said I had to send an "Electronic I.D." so that I could copyright the music and says it's mine and so forth. But the unfortunately of it is that...It never told me how to send the electronic signature to Facebook. So you can understand my frustration. So I was hoping that there would be answer so that I could put up my music.

Answer (score 4):

**How do I verify my Page to use the Music Player?**

The process to upload music using the Facebook Music Player application has changed.

In order to upload music to your Page using this application, you will need to provide an electronic signature to an agreement that confirms that you either own the copyright to the content you will be uploading or that you are authorized by the copyright owner to upload that copyrighted content to your Page.

***In order to access this agreement, please attempt to upload a song through the Facebook Music Player application***.

Per: http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=203233146379693

Answer (score 2):

You can share it through [SoundCloud](http://soundcloud.com/) and a flash player will appear on the Facebook website, I think. To do this, you have to upload your songs to SoundCloud of course and I think this will make them public.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook wanted to avoid being another MySpace, so it appears that they deliberately made it difficult-to-impossible to post pure audio links.

However, you can post video links galore to Facebook, so what I've done with my audio recordings (generally of my brother, who's a professional tenor) is turn them into a video slide show using [Fotomagico](http://www.boinx.com/fotomagico/overview/) or something similar. The key is to use software that allows you to fit the duration of your visuals to your music.

To answer your original question -- I've never even heard of this 'electronic ID.'